# Get frame count in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-media-player

Is it possible to get the number of frames in a video file, in **Windows Media Player?**

The only way I can see to do this is to either step through and count all frames, or divide the Duration by the Frame Rate.

I'm using the ActiveX Windows Media Player in Delphi.

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Comment: On the MS website and the Delphi IDE, there seems to be no such function or property.
learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp